# Why python returns None for variable that assign for itself?

Tags: python

I'm studying python, and it comes to me:

```
>>> a[0] = [1].append("test")
>>> a
[None, 2, 3, 4]
```

Expanding...

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[0] = [a[0]]
>>> a
[[1], 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[0].append(2)
>>> a
[[1, 2], 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[0].append("Batata")
>>> a
[[1, 2, 'Batata'], 2, 3, 4]
```

Why the short sentence `[1].append("test")` does not work?

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None`, that's why.

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: Try `+=` instead of `append`: `a[0] += ['whatever']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` method works in-place and returns `None`.

So, if you do the following, `b` will have the value `None`:

```
a = []
b = a.append("test")
print(b)
```

Comment: Duplicates should be closed, not answered. See the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of How to Answer.